# Split a text into words: Separators

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, split

I just used iTextSharp to get all the text from a pdf, and now I need to split that text into words. I used to use Acrobat library, which automatically divided it into words (using `getPageNthWord()`).

I don't know which criteria used, but now I need to know how to split the text into words. I will split text in different languages, so I need to split to every possible separator char.

I saw the method `Char.IsSeparator()` but using that mean looping for every char, which will be innefficient.

What I've got so far is manually specify the separators to use in the `.Split()`:

```
separators = " .,;:-(){}[]/\'""?¿!¡" & Convert.ToChar(9) & NewLine()
```

There is some place to retrieve the common separator chars?

Comment: At least in western languages, the separator for words is " ". You might add also some punctuation signs (".", ",", ":", ";"), just to account for any scenario (wrongly-written text), but I don't think that you should consider more than that. Otherwise you might start to "over-separate"; for example: "-" (or `"'"` or...) does not necessarily indicate two different words.

Comment: First, try to look at the sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta536cf.aspx. Second, may be string.Split(null) will be satisfactory?

Comment: @VladimirFrolov Both comments should be answers, IMHO. `.Split(null)` [only use white space separators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), but as you pointed, is quite similar to the `Char.IsSeparator()` filter.

Comment: @varocarbas Shouldn't I use the new line and tab chars on the split?

Comment: The Tab is implicit in " " (or null as pointed out). Regarding the new line separator, I am not sure how are you getting it via iTextSharp (you might do a couple of quick tests to confirm it); neither I am sure if the blank space accounts implicitely for it under your conditions (test it). But as said, in your position I would use the Split method as restrictively as possible in order to avoid unsolvable problems (considering two words where you really have just one) and perform a post-analysis of the given words (via Replace, for example).

Comment: See also [How to split text into words?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16725848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [string.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) with null parameter:

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

Or you can follow [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cta536cf.aspx) and get all `char.IsSeparator()` characters.