# Trying to parse a text file line by line and split lines into a jagged array of words

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to read each line of a file, line by line, and place these individual lines, divided further into an array of their individual "words" into a jagged array so that I can further manipulate them. If anyone is familiar I am attempting Day 12 of the Advent of Code Challenge so my inputs look like

```
0 <-> 780, 1330
1 <-> 264, 595, 1439
2 <-> 296, 531, 1440
```

and I would like each line to be

```
array[0][0] = 0
array[0][1] = <-> 
array[0][2] = 780
array[0][3] = 1330
array[1][0] = 1 
... etc
```

I have been working on this for like a day now and I can't seem to get C# to do this. Here is the latest stab at a solution I have been trying

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     string[][] input = new string[2000][];
     string line;
     System.IO.StreamReader file = 
     System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:/theFilePath.txt");
     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
         {
             string[] eachArray = line.Split(null);
             input[i] = new string[] { eachArray };
         }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < input[i].Length; j++)
          {
             Console.WriteLine(input[i][j]);
          }
       }
   }
```

and the error I'm getting is **"Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string"**

But shouldn't each line of the jagged array be a `string[]` and not a `string` already?

I must be missing some basic aspect of what is going on behind the scenes here.
I have tried using `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.ReadLines` and parsing them as string arrays too but the problem always comes down to instantiating the array in the loop. Can't seem to make that work.

Any other methods to solve this in C# would be welcome as well, I would just like to understand this problem better.

Comment: i suppose it should be simply `input[i] = eachArray;`. array initializer (`new string[] {  }`) can have only `string` values inside { }

Comment: I tried that too, but the problem is it will continue to print the same line over and over. Properly separated into indexes but it never advances to the next line of the file.

Comment: `line = file.ReadLine();` should be in `for` loop then.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: `input[i] = GetWords(line)`, (GetWords is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734675/1997232)) and you don't need nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` class from System.IO  has method `ReadAllLines` which can be used here.
To split each line and convert to array use `Select` and `ToArray` Linq extension methods (add required `using`s to access mentioned methods)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

string[][] input = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:/theFilePath.txt")
                       .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is even more succinct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MikeWeiss, yes, Linq often helps to shorten code, previously written in loop[s]. if my answer helped, please mark it accepted

Comment: Sorry, still a bit new to all of this, marked as accepted now, and I'll definitely be taking a closer look at Linq

Comment: good luck, take a look here [introduction-to-linq-queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)