# Split word from string

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I use this method for splitting words from string, but `\n` doesn't consider. How can I solve it?

```
public string SplitXWord(string text, int wordCount)
{
    string output = "";
    IEnumerable<string> words = text.Split().Take(wordCount);
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        output += " " + word;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split text into words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725848/how-to-split-text-into-words)

Comment: `var words = Regex.Matches(text, @"\w+");`

Comment: @Firewizz : unfortunately this splits on diacritics too. `Jalapeño` will become `Jalape` and `o`

Answer (score 2):

Well, `string.Split()` splits by *white-spaces* only

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0

> Split is used to break a delimited string into substrings. You can use either a character array or a string array to specify zero or more delimiting characters or strings. If **no delimiting characters** are specified, the string is split at **white-space** characters.

**bold** is mine.

So far so good, `string.Split()` splits on *spaces* `' '`, *tabulation* `'\t'`, *new line* `'\n'`, *carriage return* `'\r'` etc.:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", "a\nb\rc\td e".Split()));
```

produces

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

If you want to split on your cown delimiters, you should prvide them:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", "a\nb\rc\td e".Split(new char[] {' ', '\t'})));
```

note that `\r` and `\n` are preserved, when splitted on `' '` and `'t'`

```
a
b
c, d, e
```

So, it seems that your method should be something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

//DONE: static - we don't want this here
public static string SplitXWord(string text, int wordCount) {
  //DONE: don't forget about degenerated cases
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || wordCount <= 0)
    return "";

  //TODO: specify delimiters on which you want to split
  return string.Join(" ", text
    .Split(
       new char[] { ' ', '\t' },  
       wordCount + 1, 
       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Take(wordCount));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) of Split method which accepts an array of char separators and clears the empty entries

```
string str = "my test \n\r string \n is here"; 
string[] words = str.Split(new []{' ', '\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Another solution with regex and keeping line characters:

```
string str = "my test\r\n string\n is here";
var wordsByRegex = Regex.Split(str, @"(?= ).+?(\r|\n|\r\n)?").ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: i want to result be : [0] = "my" [1] = "test \n" ....

Comment: @RebinEsmaily please update your post to include a minimal reproducible example and expected output. Don't convey changes like this in comments, not everyone will see it and or understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1T5ZQ6)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myStr = "hello my friend \n whats up \n bro";
            string[] mySplitStr = myStr.Split("\n");
            mySplitStr.ToList().ForEach(str=>{
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                //to remove the white spaces 
                //Console.WriteLine(str.Replace(" ",""));
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```